# Question about proofs with topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

How would I write a proof for this example?

Let $(X, \tau_{1})$, $(Y, \tau_{2})$ and $(Z, \tau_{3})$ be topological spaces. A function ${f}: X \rightarrow Y$ is said to be continuous if for every V $\in$ $\tau_{2}$,  we have ${f^{-1}}[V]$ $\in$ $\tau_{1}$.

Suppose ${f}: X \rightarrow Y$, ${g}: Y \rightarrow Z$ is continuous. Prove that $g \circ f: X \rightarrow Z$ is continuous.

Comment: You should prove that $(g \circ f)^{-1}(A) = f^{-1}(g^{-1}(A))$. This is just a set theory argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show $g \circ f$ is continuous, you need to show it satisfies the property of continuity that you stated.  So, you need to prove if $V \in \tau_{3}$, then $(g \circ f)^{-1}(V) \in \tau_{1}$. (Note that $(g \circ f)^{-1}(V) = f^{-1}(g^{-1}(V)).)$

Here is a hint:  Use the fact that both $f$ and $g$ are continuous.  Start with $g$.  If we have $V \in \tau_{3}$, what can we say about $g^{-1}(V)$ because $g$ is continuous?  Then, what can we say about $f^{-1}(g^{-1}(V))$ because $f$ is continuous?